# Unable to create Cloud Build SMTP notifier using Cloud Run and Cloud Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have crated ***Cloud Build*** ***triggers*** to create ***CI/CD*** pipeline for a project and its working perfectly fine. Now, I want to configure ***SMTP notifications*** so the entire project team can have updates on the status of build.

***Cloud Build*** publishes status of build to ***Cloud Pub/Sub*** topic ***cloud-builds***. So to achieve this I have been following this documentation published by Google Cloud.

I have done exactly what the document says -

1. Enabled required APIs.
2. Created a secret to store my SMTP credentials.
3. Gave permission to Compute Engine default service account to access created secret.
4. Wrote a notifier configuration as documented.

```
apiVersion: cloud-build-notifiers/v1
kind: SMTPNotifier
metadata:
  name: master-deloyed-to-staging.
spec:
  notification:
    filter: build.status == Build.Status.SUCCESS
    delivery:
      server: smtp.gmail.com
      port: '587'
      sender: r@gmail.com
      from: r@gmail.com
      recipients:
      - a@gmail.com
      - b@gmail.com
      - c@gmail.com
      - d@gmail.com
      - e@gmail.com
      password:
        secretRef: dropoff-gmail
  secrets:
  - name: dropoff-gmail
    value: projects/project-id/secrets/secret-name/versions/latest
```

5. Created a bucket and uploaded the smtp-notifier.yaml to it.
6. Now this is the stage where I prepared a command to deploy notifier to cloud run. I using the image used in the documentation to deploy to cloud build

```
 gcloud run deploy dropoff-deployment-notifier \
   --image=us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/gcb-release/cloud-build-notifiers/smtp:latest \
   --update-env-vars=CONFIG_PATH=gs://dropoff-assets/cloud_run/smtp-notifier.yaml
```

Which returns me an error -

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

As, stated in error something is wrong with the PORT but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I understand that you want port _587_ since you're using Gmail. Have you tried using the flag _--port_ to specify where the container should recieve requests at? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--port

Answer (score 0):

Go to cloud run logs for this component and see the logs directly there, that is how i was able to identified the problem and eventualy fix this issue as i had the same problem.

In my case, the secret name wasn't well formatted.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib9Xf.png)